# Injecting an active controller as a dependency

Tags: autofac

Brief explanation of why I need to do this.
We're generating PDFs from HTML, and we need to render Razor views to do so. After much exploration, I came across several documents that say it's impossible without an actual controller. There is, however, two standalone Razor view libraries, however, they're both abandoned, and the latest one has an outstanding issue that prevents testing. Because of that, to test the service, we had to create a new MVC project. We just called it PdfTest and hope that it's a one off. But that doesn't fix the problem of dependencies in the actual MVC project now that we need to inject controllers.

Our constructor looks like

```
public PdfService(ControllerBase controller, string viewPath)
```

And we need an active controller to be injected in there.  Right now we're doing it from the controller like

```
public PdfController()
{
    pdfService = new PdfService(this, ...)
```

I'm guessing what I want is probably not possible.  Just asking.

Comment: I just realized if I can't solve this, it's going to be a big problem.  I have things that depend on the PdfService other than controllers.

Comment: No way to break the circular dependency? Controller => service => controller

Comment: It's not a circular dependency.  It's just more than half of the services in my application require a controller.

Comment: If your controller needs a service and that service needs the controller that is using the service... That's a circular dependency. I'd start by unravelling that.

Comment: Oh.  I see what you're saying; however the service needs an instantiated controller. That is the essence of my question. It's not really a circular dependency because Autofac is not providing the controller.  I'd like it to.  But then it wouldn't be a circular dependency either.  That's what I need to do.